# Power Automate - send Outlook email based on a list with excel attachment

Tags: excel, outlook, attachment, power-automate

I'm facing an issue when I try to send via Power Automate, Outlook Emails based on an excel file list that I have and with excel attachments.

The issue is that the excel attachments are not opening.
I'm receiving the errors: "We found a problem with some content in *file name*. Do you want us to recover us much as we can? If you trust the source of this workbook, click "Yes"."
After I click yes, I receive the message "The file is corrupted and cannot be opened".

Do you have any idea what I'm not doing ok?

I have used "get files (properties only)" and "get file content using path".

Thank you in advance for your time and support.

Cheers,
Ily

I'm expecting to be able to send Outlook emails to several people from an excel file list, with a specific attachment.

[Screenshot for flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LjUq4.png)

[Screenshot with email](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v3TFU.png)

Comment: Can you please share the screenshot of your flow please and the step where you are sending the file as an attachment

Comment: Usually, this comes when file extensions are miss matched